# Dynamically size photos instead of wrapping down

Tags: html, css, wordpress

This page:  http://blueboxluxe.com/weddings-events/  has three photos on it. What I'd like to have happen is that as the browser gets sized down smaller (to fit iPhone/iPad), those photos should shrink before they jump to the next line.

I have it working correctly on other pages (like: http://blueboxluxe.com/services/ ), but, that's a slightly different layout.

Anyways, three photos should just get smaller (along with the title overlay and green box) until the page is 768px wide (iPad), then they should jump to one per line (as it does now).

Hope this is all clear! :)

Answer (score 1):

After some experimentation with your **CSS**, it appears that doing the following should be sufficient. First, in `custom.css`, line 732 (the `.page-id-13 .ngg-thumbnail img` rule), add in `width: 100%;`.  Now in `nggallery.css`, inside `html>body .ngg-album` (line 31), add `max-width: 100%;`. This should fix your issue (works for me).

I hope that helped you in any manner!

Comment: @DrDavid Can you please post a live version of the page somewhere with the changes made, so that I can inspect around? Maybe I misexplained something.

Comment: It actually shows the thumbnails super-duper small.. But, I'll make the changes live again.

Comment: It's changed. Just those two rules were added. I tested on Chrome BTW. Works a BIT better in FF, but, still, not correct.

Comment: @DrDavid I hadn't tested on Chrome -- this is very tiny indeed! I'll keep working on it.

Comment: @DrDavid In `nggallery.css` specifically inside `html>body .ngg-album` you've inserted `width: 100%`, while I've suggested `max-width: 100%` :)

Comment: Still didn't fix it. FF has it the right size, but it doesn't scale if the screen size is just a BIT too small. Chrome is not working at all.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/15486/discussion-between-drdavid-and-abody97)